# Synchronizing dataset (.xsd file ?) to mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, xsd, dataset

With Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and MySQL 5.2.40, 
How is it possible to get visual c# to update itself after changes have been made in MySQL?

I simply added a column to a table in MySQL ( using the edit Table in the contextual menu ... the Alter Table is not available to me... could that be the problem?) and then I could not get visual studio to update it's dataset, xsd file to "refresh".  If I add myself that column in the xsd and run the simple CRUD to see if that works ... no data are saved in the mySQL database.

No refresh button, no manual addition works.  This should be simple but I am now desperate to find how to do it.

"don't forget to save and forward engineer the mySQL changes" would not be an answer to my problem ... I double checked that.

-- a newbie

Comment: Can't you completely regenerate the .xsd file?

Comment: Ha!  I was using the datamodeling tool instead of the SQL developpment tool... everything works ok now